# Notificaciones Push para Website

Tags: android, aplicación-web, push-notification, webview

Tengo una app híbrida (app web mostrada a través de un webview en Android) y quiero ponerle notificaciones push. Se que se puede hacer si entro desde una pc a un website que tenga ese servicio de notificaciones. Sin embargo, ¿se puede hacer desde una app híbrida del tipo que tengo yo? ¿Voy a ser capaz de recibir las notificaciones en mi celular (Android)?

Comment: Puedes implementar un sistema de notificaciones aprovechando la caracteristica **FCM** de la plataforma **Firebase**. Dispone de un [framework para aplicaciones web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client) que imagino que puedes utilizar con tu app híbrida.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Justamente ayer encontré esa misma info (GCM y FCM) en un video de youtube y estoy siguiendo el tutorial. Si me funciona (que creo que si lo hará), subo la respuesta acá.

Comment: Si tu aplicación es en `cordova` o `phonegap`, puedes usar `onesignal`. Sirve tanto para aplicaciones híbridas como para web. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

necesitas un service worker (PWA) y que tu aplicación esté publicada por medio de https. Te recomiendo usar el servicio de Firebase para esto.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?hl=es-419

Yo utilicé esta guía para mis aplicaciones y me funcionan bastante bien en mi aplicación Ionic 4.

https://medium.com/eleven-labs/in-a-previous-article-we-created-our-first-pwa-but-we-havent-seen-the-whole-concept-1aaed98f40a9

Lo que si tienes que hacer verificar si la aplicación es cordova o no para hacer el llamado del service.

Comment: mejora tu respuesta, ampliala pues solo colocar un enlace es de baja calidad

Comment: Complementado, gracias por la sugerencia